# Regarding Clebsch-Gordan Coefficients using Recursive method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum

So, I am reading the section on Recursion relation for Clebsch-Gordan Coefficents from Sakurai. He gives an example where he adds $J_1=l$, $l$ being an integer, and $J_2=\frac{1}{2}$. I am  following the notations given in the text book. For the case $J=l+
\frac{1}{2}$ he writes $m_1=m-\frac{1}{2}$ and $m_2=\frac{1}{2}$. I don't understand why $m_1$ is taking that value in equation $3.7.55$. Should not it be an integer value because $m_1$'s are associated with the eigen values of $J_1z$?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you assuming that $m_1=m-\frac12$ isn’t an integer? What do you think the allowed values of $m$ are?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I finally get it. So we are using the relation $m_1+m_2=m-1$ Taking $m_2$ to the other side, I get $m_1=m-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I think there is still an issue with my answer.

Comment: I don’t know how you got $m_1+m_2=m+1$. From (3.7.55) you can see that $m_1+m_2=m$. This is always true when you combine angular momenta. Furthermore, if what you wrote was true then when you take $m_2$ (which is 1/2) to the other side you would get $m_1=m-\frac32$, not $m_1=m-\frac12$.

Comment: Isnt this the equation that we are using? $\sqrt{(j+m)(j-m+1)} \bra{j_1j_2;m_1,m_2}\ket{j_1 j_2,m-1}=\sqrt{(j_1-m_1. )(j_1+m_1+1)}\bra{j_1,j_2;m_1+1, m_2}\ket{j_1 j_2;j m}+ \sqrt{(j_2+m_2+1)(j_2-m_2)}\bra{j_1 j_2;m_1,m_2+1}\ket{j_1 j_2;jm}$ . When i put $m_2=\frac{1}{2}$, the last term becomes 0 and we must have $m_1+1+m_2=m \implies m_1=m-\frac{3}{2}$? why is bra/ket notation not working here?

Comment: I don’t have the book. But from the part you’ve scanned, you can see that equation (3.7.55) clearly says $m_1=m-\frac12$.

Comment: I have added the equation which was referenced.

Comment: These are not standard mathias/latex. \bra and \ket must be macros of your local implementation system. \langle and \rangle and | ...

Comment: "mathias" $\to$ mathjax.

Answer (score 1):

You are told
$$
J=\ell +1/2, \\
m= m_1+m_2= m_1+1/2, \\
\implies ~~ m-1/2= m_1,
$$
obviously an integer, no?